# Pandas "SettingWithCopyWarning" not fixable with .loc accessor

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a DateTimeIndex and I what to add an additional column with the calendar week of the Index to the DataFrame.
My current approach is the following code and it works as expected:

```
output_df['week_number'] = output_df.index.week
```

However I receive the following warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I´ve already tried to fix it by changing to

```
output_df['week_number'] = output_df.index.week.copy()
```

but it doesn´t change anything.

Furthermore following the advice and changing to the .loc-accessor:

```
output_df.loc[:,'week_number'] = output_df.index.week
```

results in another warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)

SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[item] = s
```

What is the correct way to avoid this warning? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you create `output_df`? is this maybe a slice itself? Does `output_df.copy().index.week` solve the issue?

Comment: Great point @Cleb. "Copy earlier" seems to do it most of the time. Interested to see if this helps OP

Comment: @Cleb Yeah you´re right output_df was a slice itself. Adding `.copy()` when creating output_df solved the issue.

Comment: Marked dup has identical cause (even if the details are different); the solutions apply here too.

Comment: Glad you could solve it! Good luck with your project!